# Struggling to get a line break within table

Tags: html, html-table

I have a shoutbox within a forum I run.

It has a text input box on the left and some buttons on the right.

I would like the buttons to appear below the text input box.

Adding a < br/> tag after the  for the text input box does not help

Here's the code

```html
<!-- Text Entry Table -->
<div class="newquery">
  <form name="newshout" autocomplete="off" id="newquery">
    <table class="inputTable">
      <tr>
        <td width="100%">
          <input type="text" style="{inferno_user_css}" id="inferno_shout_entry" class="inferno_text" name="newshout"></input>
          <br />
        </td>
        <td width="1%" style="white-space:nowrap">
          <input type="submit" id="postshout" class="button" name="postshout" onclick="javascript: inferno.submit_shout(); return false;" class="submitShout" value="{$lang->isb_btn_shout}" />
          <input type="button" class="button" name="btnClear" onclick="javascript: inferno.clear_shout(); return false;" value="{$lang->isb_btn_clear}" />{inferno_button_smilies} {inferno_button_bold} {inferno_button_underline} {inferno_button_italic} {inferno_button_colors} {inferno_button_fonts}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- End Text Entry -->
```

Really stuck, so time to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the buttons in a new `<tr>` element. Here's a quick mock-up:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Text Area/Form Field
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Submission Buttons Here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Kyle. I modded the code with an extra <tr> and closed it too (i believe it needs closing?) Then ran through the W3 tryit editor and correct the buttons move below the text box. However when I update the actual file and upload to my server, it doesn't work. Checked the code in chrome dev tools and looks like the new tags may have been stripped. The site is guardiancrosszone.com :D

Comment: Could be a caching issue. Try a cntrl+F5 refresh to see if the page updates after the changes were made.

Comment: That's what I thought. Already done Ctrl+F5 and also manually cleared the chrome cache and no affect on the styling.

Comment: fixed it, Thanks for the help Kyle. There we're some nasty php template files within the forum undoing the code change on the main html file. Corrected it using your method